# Selenium IDE: Comparing two variables

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm using the Selenium IDE on chrome (version 3.4.4)
I want to test if clicking a button adds a new row to a table.

I thought I'd just:

1. count the rows of the table before clicking (store the number in a variable)
2. clicking the button
3. count the rows of the table again and store this number in a different variable
4. Check if the second variable is one higher than the first

How do I do this?
If there are better solutions to this problem I'll be happy to hear them.